# Which one is better to use for interacting cassandra with java?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I need to insert and pull the data from AWS C* table.
My producer of data is defined with Spring Boot with Java8.

So which one  I should I use for my project which is stable and efficient.
I got ways ( here I guess)
1. Sprinda-data-JPA.
2. cassandra-driver-core of datastax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: Questions like this...asking which tool/library is "better" is subjective, and isn't usually a good fit for Stack Overflow.

That being said, the Spring Data Cassandra driver inherently violates two known Cassandra data access anti-patterns (that I know of):

- Unbound `SELECT COUNT(*)` as a part of their paging mechanism.
- Use of `BATCH` for multiple writes.

Additionally, the Spring Data Cassandra driver uses the DataStax driver, providing an additional delay for bug fixes and upgrades.

**tl;dr;**

You cannot go wrong by using the DataStax Java driver, and I *highly* recommend its use.

Comment: Agreeing on this. We run into multiple problems with the spring data cassandra driver and moved back to the datastax java driver. If you need paging and complex searches you should consider DSE or elassandra.

Comment: @AlexTbk & Aaron , is there any sample git code to use DataStax driver with spring boot ?

Comment: Not really well readable in a comment here, but I try:     public BaseRepository(final CassandraOperations cassandra, Session session) {
        this.cassandra = cassandra;
        this.session = session;
    }

    protected T fetchOne(final Select select) {
        select.setFetchSize(FETCH_SIZE);
        select.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM);
        return cassandra.selectOne(select, getGenericTypeClass());
    }